# How can I install PIKLAB on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, install-from-source

I'm trying to install PIKLAB IDE for Microchip PIC controllers programming but got stuck at an error message as below:

```
-- Could NOT find Threads (missing:  Threads_FOUND) 
CMake Error at /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/FindQt4.cmake:420 (FILE):
  file Internal CMake error when trying to open file:
  /home/bnh/Downloads/piklab-0.16.2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmpQmake/tmp.pro for
  writing.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Install piklab on Ubuntu 11.04 and later](http://photonics.engr.uga.edu/piklab/index.html) piklab is based on QT3 and as such is not easily installable on recent versions of Ubuntu.

The above mentioned page is a tutorial as well and suggests to

- install command line utilities

  - gputils
  - sdcc
- install libraries

  - libreadline6
  - libusb
  - libstdc++
  - kdelibs5-data
  - liblua50
  - liblualib50
  - libqt3-mt
  - launchpad-integration
- install packages not available from the repositories (download the *deb* files)

  - [kdelibs-data_3.5.10.dfsg.1-5ubuntu2_all.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/68040450/kdelibs-data_3.5.10.dfsg.1-5ubuntu2_all.deb)
  - [libavahi-qt3-1_0.6](http://us.archive.trisquel.info/trisquel/pool/main/a/avahi/libavahi-qt3-1_0.6.30-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb)
- get a [debian package of piklab](http://pkgs.org/debian-squeeze/debian-main-amd64/piklab_0.15.7-1_amd64.deb.html) (it is a bit old..) and install it

*Steps completely taken from the mentioned page.*

Additionally the tutorial references another blog: [How to setup a PIC microcontroller development environment](http://thebitbangtheory.blogspot.pt/2011/10/how-to-setup-pic-microcontroller.html) which uses *rpm* packages with `alien`, a somewhat problematic approach on Ubuntu with the advantage of getting a current version of piklab.